# Question about increasing sequences

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-writing, proof-explanation

[image]

We've started going over sequences and I'm not sure how to prove that the sequence converges in the extended sense.. I thought about splitting it into cases, one in which the sequence is bounded and one where it's not but without any luck so far. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the sequence is bounded above by $M \in \Bbb R$, then $s:=\sup\{a_n\mid n=1,2,3\ldots\}$ exists as a real number. Then show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = s$, using the definition of supremum and the increasingness.

If the sequence is unbounded, for every $M\in \Bbb R$, there must be some $n$ such that $a_n > M$ but then the tail of the sequence (from this $n$ onwards) is in $(M, +\infty]$ by increasingness, so $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = +\infty$ by definition.